# Datetime from MySQL in Kafka is converted to wrong timestamp (for dates less than year 0100)

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, timestamp, debezium

Why datetime from MySQL in Kafka is converted to wrong timestamp (for dates less than year 0100) ?

I have a table with a datetime column, where I insert the value 0078-10-15 10:00:00.0000000, timestamp = 277293600000 appears in kafka for this row (human date from online timestamp converter is 15 10 1978, 10:00:00) .

The MySQL documentation says:

> "Dates containing two-digit year values   are ambiguous because the
> century is unknown. MySQL interprets two-digit year values   using
> these rules:
>
> Year values   in the range 70-99 become 1970-1999.
>
> Year values   in the range 00-69 become 2000-2069."

And it really does work like this, but the date in the database looks like this: 0078-10-15 10:00:00.0000000, i.e. century is specified.

For years greater than 0099 everything works fine and the timestamp is **-many digits**

Debezium connector configuration:

```
{
"name": "source-param-datetime",
"config": {
        "connector.class" : "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",

        "database.hostname": "hostname",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "user",
        "database.password": "password",
        "database.server.id" : "12",
        "database.server.name": "erp_pd",
        "database.include.list": "bgcrm_v21",

        "table.include.list": "bgcrm_v21.param_datetime",

        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "server",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.erp.param_datetime",
        "include.schema.changes": "false",
        "snapshot.mode": "schema_only",
        "snapshot.locking.mode" : "minimal_percona",

        "transforms": "unwrap",

        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones" : "false",

        "key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081",

        "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081",
 
        "name": "source-param-datetime"
        }
}
```

Thought the problem was
time.precision.mode and try different values ​​for this setting but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

"enable.time.adjuster" : "false"

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-property-enable-time-adjuster